# Import issue while using the python setuptools library

Tags: python, setuptools, google-ai-platform

I am using the python library setuptools. I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: numpy>=1.17 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found numpy==1.16.5.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git master
```

However, I am already declaring numpy with the version 1.17 in the setup file:

```
%%writefile custom/setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['torch>=1.5', 'scikit-learn>=0.20', 'pandas', 'transformers', 'numpy>=1.17', 'tensorboard']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My training application package.'
)
```

So, is something wrong with the setup file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be `numpy>=1.17` coming *after* `transformer`, so numpy still stays at 1.16.5 when transformer is installed.
I haven't dug into setuptools, so it's just a guess :)

Comment: could be, I'll try! Thanks